# gRPC server Threadpool Exhausted

Tags: grpc, grpc-c++

i have gRPC sync server with one service and 1 RPC.

I am not setting ResourceQuota on serverbuilder.
If n clients wants to connect, there will be n request handler threads created by gRPC. I want to keep some limit on these threads. lets say 10. And if it costs some latency in serving client, it is okay.

So I tried these settings:

```
  grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
  grpc::ResourceQuota rq;
  rq.SetMaxThreads(10);
  builder.SetResourceQuota(rq);
  builder.SetSyncServerOption(
      grpc::ServerBuilder::SyncServerOption::MIN_POLLERS, 1);
  builder.SetSyncServerOption(
      grpc::ServerBuilder::SyncServerOption::MAX_POLLERS, 1);
  builder.SetSyncServerOption(grpc::ServerBuilder::SyncServerOption::NUM_CQS,
                              1);
```

From another process, I am firing up 800 clients in parallel. So I expect there will be 1 completion queue for each of them and 10 threads sharing it.
However, on client side there is an error:

"**Server Threadpool Exhausted**"

and none of the client succeeds. how to share threads between different clients.

Comment: Would you be able to show how you spawn you 800 clients in parallel? I cannot recreate the problem. Update: reproduced with `seq 1 800 | parallel ./client` but it didn't fail all the clients, just few of them.

Comment: @ClémentJean i am spawning 800 threads and then calling write for them in loop. First of all it should be able to share the threads right? Why it is failing

Comment: Like write in general or you mean the `Write` from the streaming APIs ? In other words do you have 800 streamings running ?

Comment: @ClémentJean `write` from streaming APIs. Yes 800 streaming running